# Best approach to find how many times particular string is repeating using which collection in java?

Tags: java

String array of size 100 eg: {'Hemant','Mahesh','ABC'...}
1.requirement: find the strings count, how many times particular string is found?
eg: Hemant 2 | Mahesh 5
2.Which is the best collection to implement the same? How to implement it?

Comment: You can use HashMap for it.http://learnwebtechs.com/2017/03/11/java-hashmap-to-count-words-in-a-sentence

Comment: A map of strings to frequencies

Comment: so while implementing the same to count the particular String like eg: Hemant 2
do i need to write 2 for each loop first one for String and other for its count???

Comment: @KrishnaSingh got the answer thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Stream.of(stringArray)
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
          Collectors.counting())) // A map of the strings with their count
     .entrySet().stream()
     .forEach(e -> System.out.printf("%20s : %d%n", e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

This uses streams to create a Map of string to its frequency.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stream` as below,

```
Map<String, Integer> countMap = Arrays.stream(split)
.collect(toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

Here, first Array is converted to stream (you could use `Stream.of(array)` as well) then collecting each key with [Function.identity()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) and initial value to 1 (v->1) and then incrementing by 1 if key already present. `toMap` is static import for `Collectors.toMap`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind you code? Thanks.

Comment: Yes please..can you elaborate?? thanks

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah...got it..thanks